# Assign a underscore to a variable. What is the underscore doing?

Tags: scala

Recently I've run into code like this:

```
var myVariable: variableKind = _
```

It seems to be a way to assign `null` to `myVariable`.

Can anyone explain the rationale behind `_` in this case? 
What are the differences between assigning `_` and `null` to a variable?

Comment: FYI I've extended your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364677/difference-between-underscore-initialization-of-var-and-val

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It initialises the variable with it's default value - this value depends on the type. For numeric types, this is `zero`, `false` for booleans, `()` for `Unit` and null for types extending `AnyRef`.

Comment: So, in short, this syntax is a replacement for uninitialized java fields? `var x: Int = _` -> `int x;`, `var y: Integer` -> `Integer y;`?

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly, yes, it is usually used exactly for that, since you can't have uninitialized vars/vals in Scala.

Answer (score 2):

The value assigned depends on the declared type. If your "variableKind" extends AnyRef, the default value (for any object) is null. For numeric types it's zero, etc.