# Difference between underscore initialization of var and val

Tags: scala

Why does `val x: Int = _` not compile but `var x: Int = _` does?

I'm getting `error: unbound placeholder parameter`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In this context, `_` means "I will initialize this later, just fill in whatever the sensible default is in the meantime".  Since you can't reassign a `val`, this doesn't make sense.

For the same functionality--to get the sensible default--for a `val`, you can use

```
val x: Int = null.asInstanceOf[Int]
```

Comment: That's a good explanation because people often say that underscore means default value, but it's not. Thanks

Comment: @RadoBuransky It _does_ mean default value. This answer applies to the code style: it's a _bad idea_ to access this default value before reassigning the `var`, but it's legal and you won't get compilation errors or runtime exceptions.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I understand, but if it was simply the default value then assignment to a `val` should compile, but it doesn't. I am not talking about whether it makes sense. I just wanted to say that `_` does not equal to default value of a given type.

Answer (score 2):

You can't reassign a vals value, so you cannot use _ (init with a default value for prescribed type) with it. But you can reassign a vars value, so it's a logical to initialize it with some default value, like in Java